# Prove that $AB = 0 \iff \mathrm{im}(B) \subseteq \ker(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem 1.** Prove that for any $\ell \times m$-matrix $A$ and any $m \times n$-matrix $B$,

$$
AB = 0 \quad\text{ if and only if }\quad \mathrm{im}(B) \subseteq \ker(A)
$$

I have no idea on how to start this... 
I'm new to proofs and this is my first proof.

Comment: To the down voter and future candidate down voters. Is it inconceivable to you that someone really has nothing even remotely tangible to say regarding the problem, considering this person hasn't been exposed to proofs yet?

Comment: I would say an important step towards understanding is that matrix multiplication means composition of linear maps. Then the proof would be clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $AB = 0$. Let $x\in \operatorname{Im}(B)$. Then $x = By$ for some $y$. So $$Ax = A(By) = (AB)y = 0y = 0.$$ Thus $x\in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$.

Conversely, assume $\operatorname{Im}(B) \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}(A)$. For every $x$, $Bx \in \operatorname{Im}(B)$ and thus $Bx \in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$, i.e., $ABx = 0$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $AB = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

suppose $AB = 0$.  you need to show $im B \subset ker A$  so pick an element $y$ in $im B$ that means $y = Bx$ for some $x.$ look at $Ay = ABx = 0$ because $AB = 0.$ now we have shown that for any $y \in im B $ implies $Ay = 0$ so $y \in kerA$ we are done showing if $AB = 0$, then $im B \subset ker A$

suppose $im B \subset ker A,$ we need to show $AB = 0$ we will show it by contradiction. suppose $AB \neq 0.$ that means there is an $x$ such that $ABx \neq 0$ since $Bx \in im B$ and $im B \subset ker A$. that means $Bx \in kerA$  and $ABx = 0$ the contradiction we sought.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to show these two facts:

1)If $im(B) \subseteq ker(A)$ then $AB=0$. Hint for this: use the fact that a vector $y$ is in the image of $B$ if there exists a vector $x$ such that $Bx=y$.

2) If $AB=0$ then $im(B) \subseteq ker(A)$. Hint: use the above characterization of $im(B)$ and the definition of $ker(A)$.